# Get PHP file out of a variable?

Tags: php

How can I out from a variable like this:
`$var1 = "www.game.mysite.com/folder/page.php?var1=1&var2=2";`

And then I want somehow to get only the "page.php", what ever it is set to be?

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean the name of the php file or do you mean the content of the php file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use a regex for that, but [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$var1 = "www.game.mysite.com/folder/page.php?var1=1&var2=2";
$parsed = parse_url($var1);
var_dump(basename($parsed['path']));
```

See the example on [codepad](http://codepad.org/llrgaLXY).

Answer (score 2):

This will use the last segment of the path.

```
$var1 = "www.game.mysite.com/folder/page.php?var1=1&var2=2";
$path = parse_url($var1, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path_parts = explode('/', $path);
var_dump($path_parts[count($path_parts) -1]);
```

Outputs:

```
string(8) "page.php"
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see jeroen's answer, his is best.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple regex will get you out of trouble:

```
$var1 = "www.game.mysite.com/folder/page.php?var1=1&var2=2";
preg_match('/([a-z]+\.php)/', $var1, $file); // Returns `page.php`
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the preg_match method that tehlulz mentioned, or also a preg_replace option in the event you don't know what the file extension is.

```
$pattern = '/(.*)(\/)(.*)(\?)(.*)/';
$replacement = '$3';
$filename = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $var1);
```

There are several ways to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$var1 = "www.game.mysite.com/folder/page.php?var1=fgsd rew1&var2=2";
$reversed_string = strrev($var1);
$pos_of_questionMark = strpos($reversed_string, "?");
$pos_of_first_slash = strpos($reversed_string, "/");
$getfilename = strrev(substr($reversed_string,$pos_of_questionMark+1,  $pos_of_first_slash-$pos_of_questionMark-1));
echo $getfilename;
```